# Why would deleting working files and then calling Git reset hard result in different statuses

Tags: windows, git

This is happening on a repo on Windows 7 using Git 1.8.3

I have a group of files that when I follow this workflow:

- delete them locally (using the file system)
- git reset --hard
- git status

some of the files will show up as changed, and some will not, but which ones are in each set changes each time I follow the workflow. (i.e. files A and C will be marked different one time, then B and D will be different the next)

I've already tried every combination of autoclrf and case sensitivity - neither seem to have any effect.

All of the files are tracked by git.

What could be causing this, and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: `git reset --hard` should reset your branch and make your working tree match that commit. Therefore I would expect `git status` to be empty. Can you give an example for which this is not true?

Comment: It would be perfect, if you could set up a minimal example repository, together with some commands that demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @michas That is precisely the behaviour that I would expect as well - hence the question. The funny thing is that when I use an external diffing tool, it says that they are "binary same". As for a minimum working repro - I'm afraid that I can't even get it to repro from a clone of the same repo. I am happy to supply any log or .git information that might help, though.